# Change thumbnail options on an OpenCart product page

Tags: image, thumbnails, opencart

I'm currently trying to work with opencart but I need to change the way the product page works, currently, I have a primary image of the product and some thumbnails to the right, when you click on a thumbnail it brings up a large image to view. Instead of that I would like it so that when you click on a thumbnail, it changes the primary image to which ever thumbnail you select.

Here is example of what is currently happening: http://nthwondr.com/

Does anyone know of a way to change it to what I need?

Comment: Either learn JavaScript (jQuery is the way in this case) or search for [existing extensions](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=hover%20on%20image%20to%20change%20main%20im)...

Comment: I have found a way of doing, first is must be on-click rather then hover which I have done but the only problem I face now is that I need the new image to slide in rather then just change.

Comment: There is a big difference between *I need* and *I want* (i.e. between *necessary* and *nice to have*)...

Comment: Yes there is and I was right in what I said, although I guess if you wanted to get into detail about it, it comes down to perspective, for what I am doing I need it, but generally speaking I could live without it, that's like saying you don't _need_ money but if you want to live nicely you do _need_ money... all depends on which point of view you are seeing it from.

Comment: Sure, but from my point of view any kind of animation (and sliding a new image to replace the old one **is only an animation**) will always be **only nice to have** (thus a thing one may want, not need for life). Share your current working code and maybe someone here could help you ;-)

Comment: I have posted it up in a new question as I already solved half of the problem with new coding and mods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171568/adding-animation-to-image-change